# Why can't a class with a type parameter used exclusively as an argument type be covariant on it?

Tags: c#, covariance

The most common example I have found to explain why contravariantly-valid type parameters cannot be used covariantly has involved constructing some read-write wrapper of a derived type, casting it to a wrapper of the base type, injecting a different derived type, *then later reading that wrapped value*; something along the lines of the following:

```
class Base { public int base_property; }
class Derived : Base { public int derived_property; }
class OtherDerived : Base { public string other_derived_property; }
interface Wrapper<out T> {
  void put(T v);
  T pull();
}
Wrapper<Derived> derived_wrapper = new WrapperImpl<Derived>();
Wrapper<Base> cast_wrapper = (Wrapper<Base>)derived_wrapper;
cast_wrapper.put(new OtherDerived());
Derived wrapped = derived_wrapper.pull(); // Surprise! This is an OtherDerived.
```

I can understand why this is invalid. But what if `Wrapper` didn't have `pull`, and the property it wraps has a private getter? The problem with the `(Wrapper<Base>)derived_wrapper` cast seems to disappear, and I can't find a problem to replace it.

More specifically, I'm not aware of any way for functionality to be conditional on the eventual concrete type of a generic. Unsurprisingly, asserting the type like the following is no use:

```
class WrapperImpl<T> : Wrapper<T> where T : Base {
  public void put(T v) {
    if(typeof(T).Equals(Derived)) {
      Console.WriteLine(v.derived_property); // Type `T' does not contain a
                                             // definition for `derived_property'...
    }
  }
}
```

This leads me to believe that functionality in these methods can only make use of properties of the type `T` is constrained to. Even if the wrapped property is an `OtherDerived` where the original `WrapperImpl` expected a `Derived` (before being cast), no method could expect that wrapped property to have `derived_property` because `Base` is the most specific `T` is guaranteed to be.

Am I missing something here, or perhaps is this a limitation of the compiler to not be able to concretize `T` on the fly?

(I'm guessing that a class like `Wrapper` finds few uses, but the rules of variance appear quite broad and sweeping, and I'm curious if there are finer rules in play.)

Answer (score 0):

The `T` in `WrapperImpl<T>` can be constrained on **any subtype of `Base`**, not just `Base` itself. Functionality in `put` should be able to safely access `v.derived_property` if `T : Base` is simply changed to a `T : Derived`.

This is the source of trouble when an `OtherDerived` is passed to `put` after the `(Wrapper<Base>)derived_wrapper` cast, in trying to access the nonexistent `derived_property`.